# node.js/request.js ignores NO_PROXY environment variable

Tags: javascript, node.js

I set the HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY and NO_PROXY environment variables (both in upper and lower case) on my Mac. When I try to make an HTTP request using request.js, the HTTP_PROXY setting is respected. However, when I try to access a server whose domain is set in the NO_PROXY variable, I get a 503 error. It seems that the NO_PROXY variable is ignored.

Does anyone know how I can tell Node.js/request.js to ignore certain domains when going through the proxy (without implementing it on my own)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `no_proxy` is ignored in `mikeal/request`. See this issue:
https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/620

It looks like he's willing to accept a fix, but nobody has written it yet. If you offer up a solution, many people would appreciate it.

Comment: The issue was fixed 10 days later! NO_PROXY is supported now. :)